# How can i integrated subscription payment model in apple pay?

Tags: ios, applepay

Is there any information where we can create recurring payment using apple pay?

Comment: It isn't a direct function of Apple Pay - It is a function of your payment processor - See https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-apple-pay-for-recurring-payments as an example